# Metawidgetjs tabs is not working insight the iframe on IE browser

Tags: jquery-ui-tabs, metawidget

I am using metawidgetJs, Tabs are never support into the IE if it call from Iframe. I share basic sample code.

Here is basic html file if I open this file into the IE it's working fine, But if I call this file from Iframe into another file and open this new one file into IE browser tabs are destroy.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <script src="http://metawidget.sourceforge.net/js/4.2/metawidget-core.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script src="http://metawidget.sourceforge.net/js/4.2/metawidget-jqueryui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var person = {
            "myname":"no angular js",                   
                "contact":'contact',
              "dimensions": 'dimensions'   
        };
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        <div id="metawidget"></div>
    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var mw = new metawidget.Metawidget( document.getElementById( 'metawidget' ), {
            inspector: new metawidget.inspector.CompositeInspector( [ new metawidget.inspector.PropertyTypeInspector(),
                function( toInspect, type, names ) {    
                    return {
                        properties: {
                                "myname":{                      
                                "title":"Name",
                                "section":"Personal Details",
                                "type":"string",
                                 "required":"true",
                                 "pattern":"^(0|[1-9][0-9]*)$"
                            },
                            "contact":{
                                "title":"Contact",
                                "section":"Contact Information",
                                "type":"string",
                                 "required":"true",
                                 "pattern":"^(0|[1-9][0-9]*)$"
                                        },
                            "dimensions":{
                                "title":"Aggrigation Dimention",
                                "section":"Dim",
                                "type":"string",
                                 "required":"true",
                                 "pattern":"^(0|[1-9][0-9]*)$"
                            }
                        }
                    };
                } ] ),
            layout: new metawidget.jqueryui.layout.TabLayoutDecorator(
                new metawidget.layout.DivLayout( { numberOfColumns: 2 } ))
        } );        
        mw.toInspect = person;
        mw.buildWidgets();
    </script>
</body>
```

And this is my another file. When I open this one by calling first file into this iframe, IE browser destroy the tabs

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <iframe src="firstFile.html" width="500" height="500">
    </iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see 2 problems with your sample:

**First Problem**

On all browsers, the tabs are functional but hard to see. This is because there is no CSS styling. You have left out the stylesheet reference in your `<head>`. I added:

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css"/>`

And now tabs appear in both IFRAME and non-IFRAME versions, on browsers other than IE.

**Second Problem**

The IE-specific behaviour appears to be covered by this bug: https://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/8653

This is meant to be fixed, but it seems something Metawidget was doing was triggering it. I've tried a workaround here: https://github.com/metawidget/metawidget/commit/13f34e22ad71d82f30fb502bfb0a6246c47595a4.

Built here: https://kennardconsulting.ci.cloudbees.com/job/Metawidget/371

Please test.

Comment: My problem is only second, the tab is not working insight the Iframe in IE browser. I am using IE-11

Comment: That was really great & quick solution, thank you so much I was looking for this for years, stack is gr8 because of people like you :)